# Comparison Variables

Tags: javascript, variables

I saw some variables like this:

```
var comparison = <condition> || /* It could be "&&" too */ <condition>;
```

I don't know what it is and what can it do?
Tks you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're called [logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) (MDN):

> **`expr1 && expr2`** : Returns expr1 if it can be converted to false; otherwise, returns expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, && returns true if both operands are true; otherwise, returns false.
>
> **`expr1 || expr2`** : Returns expr1 if it can be converted to true; otherwise, returns expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, || returns true if either operand is true; if both are false, returns false.

Comment: @ruakh I've changed my quote selection.

Answer (score 3):

It's mainly used to initialize function arguments to a certain default value.

```
function foo(arg1,arg2)
{
    arg1 = arg1 || 'Default for arg1';
    arg2 = arg2 || 'Default for arg2';
}
```

What this code does, is actually the same as the following:

```
if (!(arg1))
{//if arg1 is falsy
    arg1 = 'Default for arg1';//assign
}
```

As far as the `&&` goes, that's pretty much the same story:

```
function foo(arg1,arg2)
{
    var areBothArgsTrue  = arg1 && arg2;//sets true is both args were truthy, else assigns false
    arg1 = arg1 || 'Default for arg1';
    arg2 = arg2 || 'Default for arg2';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code will evaluate the two condition and will return a boolean value.

`var comparison = 2 > 1 && 3 < 1;`

In this case, `comparison` will be set to `false`.

`&&` will return `true` only if both condition are true, while `||` will return `true` if at least one condition is `true`.

Comment: That is not the same as the case in the original question. Elias Van Ootagem's answer is correct.